# Load MaterialDesignIcons in Vuetify project without css cdn reference

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I have a project which uses MaterialDesignIcons in Nuxt with Vuetify.

Today I switch completely with all  tags to the JS loading type:
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/icon-fonts/#material-design-icons-js-svg

```
<v-icon>{{ mdiCheck }}</v-icon>
(...)
import { mdiCheck, mdiCart } from '@mdi/js'
(...)
  data() {
return {
  mdiCheck,
  mdiCart,
```

my problem is, that after yarn build / start the loading of the css file from cdn don't stop.

[image]

How can I see why this is still loaded and how to fix this?

In Head HTML:

Comment: of course I switch to 'mdiSvg' as IconFont in the Settings and also added '@mdi/js' package...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a problem with the nuxt plugin for vuetify.

As you can see in [their docs](https://github.com/nuxt-community/vuetify-module#defaultassets) they by default load the Roboto font and Material Design Icons. Difficult to spot but easy to fix:

In `nuxt.config.js` set `defaultAssets: false` in the vuetify configuration:

```js
vuetify: {
  defaultAssets: false,
  icons: {
     iconfont: 'mdiSvg',
  }
}
```